# Is there a non-deprecated clean way to append a series or an array to just one of a dataframe's column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with two columns and a series, I want to attach this series to the end of a column and have the values of the other one set to NaN. These appended values should not be merged with what is already in the df. I know there is append, but that is deprecated so I wondered what the alternatives were for this task nowadays.

This is what I did and how I want it to look in the end (without the conversion to float for some reason):

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1, 2, 3], 'two': [4, 5, 6]})
b = pd.Series([7, 8, 9], name='two')
pd.concat([a, pd.DataFrame({'one': np.nan, 'two': b})], ignore_index=True)
```

```
    one two
0   1.0 4
1   2.0 5
2   3.0 6
3   NaN 7
4   NaN 8
5   NaN 9
```

This would be more problematic with more columns and I just wanted a cleaner way for the sake of it.

Comment: To avoid the float conversion, change `np.nan` to `pd.NA` in your `concat` line. If you pad with `np.nan`, pandas automatically converts to `float` because `np.nan` cannot coexist with `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) works fine without needing to manually pad, just convert your Series [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1, 2, 3], 'two': [4, 5, 6]})
b = pd.Series([7, 8, 9], name='two')

out = pd.concat([a.convert_dtypes(), b.to_frame()], ignore_index=True)
```

*NB. the [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) enables to use a NA that avoids conversion to float. Also, the name of the Series is important to assign the column, if the Series doesn't already have a name use `to_frame(name='two')`.*

Output:

```
    one  two
0     1    4
1     2    5
2     3    6
3  <NA>    7
4  <NA>    8
5  <NA>    9
```

Comment: also note that naming the series `name='two'` is key in this case

Comment: @tdy yes of course, thanks for the precision! If the name wasn't already there, then `to_frame(name='two')` would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1, 2, 3], 'two': [4, 5, 6]})
b = pd.Series([7, 8, 9], name='two')
a = a.to_dict('list')
a['two'].extend(b)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index').T
```

If you have more columns, use a `for` loop for the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1, 2, 3], 'two': [4, 5, 6]})
b = pd.Series([7, 8, 9], name='two')

c = a.merge(a['two'].append(b).reset_index(drop=True), how='outer')

print(c)
```

**Result**

```
   one  two
0  1.0    4
1  2.0    5
2  3.0    6
3  NaN    7
4  NaN    8
5  NaN    9
```